# Can't access to an iframe with a NuxtJS PWA

Tags: google-chrome, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps

We implemented a PWA with Nuxtjs.
We use the pwa module.

The app is quite simple (it's a product catalog) but for each product, we call an iframe.
This iframe call static files included in a static folder.

When I am online, I have no issue but when I get offline, I still can navigate in the app but when I display the product, the iframe can't be loaded and show me the following error :

> the webpage at — might be temporarily down or it may have moved
> permanently to a new web address

I don't know how to fix it.

### EDIT:

Here is my nuxtjs app folder

[image]

I call the iframe with the following code :

```html
<iframe
  v-if="product.configurationId"
  ref="iframe"
  class="viewer rounded shadow"
  :src="'/3d/index.html?ref=' + product.configurationId"
  allowfullscreen
  border="0"
/>
```

Let's say the app url is https://myapp.com/
When I call the iframe, the following url is called https://myapp.com/3d/index.html?ref=refProduct

### EDIT WITH CACHE STORAGE DETAILS

Following kissu comment, I take a look in the Dev Tool cache storage.
I have 4 cache files :

- workbox-precache-V2
- workbox-runtime
- my app cache
- a second app cache

In workbox-runtime cache, I can see the files from the 3D folder.

Comment: Not sure if this is enough for people to help you. I'd say that you need to make sure that Workbox is loading all of your assets offline and not waiting to load them in an async way with prefetch because you may not reach this point. I know that by default, the module is not downloading the pages for a 100% offline mode, maybe look into this one. And maybe give us a [repro], it may help us debug it faster!

Comment: Tkank's kissu. I added some details to the question. Maybe it could help.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm not a PWA expert tho, but maybe someone else could help if they're passing by.